# implementing exit dialog into android activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement an exit dialog to the user when he presses the back button, but when he presses it, it sends him to the precedent activity without displaying the dialog.

Here is `onBackPressed():`

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Closing Activity")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }
```

Comment: Semi-related design note: Every time I see a "Are you sure..." dialog instead of normal behavior, it makes me want to throttle someone. Unless it's something potentially damaging, just let it go back.

Comment: @Geobits I agree even though a lot of "Mainstream" apps do it. Even my Lenovo tablet asks if I'm sure I want to power down. That's why I hit the power button. As a user, it is very frustrating unless there may be unsaved data or something of the like

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `.Create()` and just a suggestion of adding `super.finish()` exit the parent Activity too.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("Closing Activity")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
       {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           super.finish();    
        }

        })
      .setNegativeButton("No", null)
      .create().show();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the call to super.finish() is necessary, but the .create() certainly is.

Comment: Agreed with @Tanis.7x - calling `super.finish()` isn't correct. The `onClick(...)` method is part of the anonymous `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and not part of the `Activity`.